# Loop is only storing spaces into the array after the first character it scans

Tags: java

So my main goal is to create a program that can decrypt a caesar cipher. I have everything set up so that I have the regular alphabet set up in one array and then a decoder array where I have shifted the alphabet based on a shift/key the user inputs. (ie. if the user inputs a shift of 6, the regular alphabet array starts a, b, c... and then the decoder array starts g, h, i...).

I currently am trying to decrypt "O znotq iusvazkx yioktik oy gckyusk" which says "I think computer science is awesome" with a Caesar shift of 6. The problem with my code right now is that it is correctly decrypting the first character "O" to "I" and the space after it but then everything after that is a space too.

The output I'm getting right now is "I_____" where the underscores are spaces (5 spaces).

Here is the section of code decrypting the message:

```
//Decoding message by looping through each letter in String message
for (int x = 0; x < (message.length() - 1); x ++) //Gets next letter in message
{
    if (message.charAt(x) == ' ') //Checking for spaces
    {
        decodedMessage[x] = ' ';
    }
    else
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < (decodedArray.length - 1); y++) //Goes through decodedArray array
        {
            if (message.charAt(x) == (decodedArray[y]))
            {
                decodedMessage[x] = alphabetArray[y];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My decoder array is set up by the following code by shifting alphabet array (which is an array of chars) by a certain number of shifts.

```
int count = 0;

//Adds alphabet from starting position (key) to end of alphabet/array for (int x = key; x < 26; x++)
{
    decodedArray[count] = alphabetArray[x];
    count++;
}
//Adding rest of alphabet to end of decodedArray
for (int x = 0; x < key; x++)
{
    decodedArray[count] = alphabetArray[x];
    count++;
}
```

Comment: share your decoded array also

Comment: I'd bet that the comparison `message.charAt(x) == (decodedArray[y])` is where your error is. I would also guess that it has something to do with their types

Comment: You don't need any arrays. You can just subtract the shift: `decodedChar = (char) ((encodedChar - 'a' + 26 - shift) % 26 + 'a')` (example for lowercase only).

Comment: If you must use arrays, I think you can use: `decodedMessage[x] = alphabetArray[decodedArray.indexOf(message.chatAt(x))]`. Also this is a prime candidate for `map` instead of the loop.

Comment: *Curious:* Why don't you want to process the last element in the arrays? `for` loops should go while `i < len` or `i <= len - 1`, not while `i < len - 1`.